# How can I run matching values in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

I have two arrays and I want to be able to compare the two arrays and return only the matching values. For example, both arrays have the value of date 2023/03/07 so that is the value to be returned. I haven't found anything like this. What is the best way to return the similarity?

```
var array1 = ['2023/03/07','2023/03/17','2023/03/27'];
var array2 = [];
var startDate = '2023/03/05';
var endDate = '2023/03/15';
var dateMove = new Date(startDate);
var strDate = startDate;    
while (strDate < endDate){
    var strDate = dateMove.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    array2.push(strDate);
    dateMove.setDate(dateMove.getDate()+1);         
};//console.log(array2);    
found = array1.find((val, index) => {
    return array2.includes(val);                
})
console.log(found); 
//if value in array1 is equal to value in array2 then return match: 2023/03/07
```

Comment: the problem you're facing is that `toISOString` is using `-` as a delimiter but your array1 is using `/` as a delimiter. If you change your delimiter in array1 to `-` your code works.

Comment: ok. thank's for your answer.

Comment: Am  i crazy or does the code you posted just work out of the box? i just tested it on my won, a direct copy past in  to a vanilla js file, added '2023/03/17/` to `array2` and it worked. is this not the intended function?

Comment: how can i add an html in the presentation 
 $('.show').html(found.'<span>an html</span>');

Comment: '2023/03/17' is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. In Safari at lest, `new Date('2023/03/17')` returns an invalid date. Given the timestamps are strings, there's no need for conversion to *Date* at all, just compare as strings. And the similarity to ISO 8601 format means `<` and `>` work as required also.